# Drawing Parabola using DrawLine C#

Tags: c#, graph

Good evening, I know on the web there are similar questions and a few tutorials about it, but I'd like you to check my code and correct it.   I mean, I'd like to know what's wrong with my project.
I have to draw a parabola graph given its equation on my main panel. 
I  also must include two buttons, zoom in and zoom out, which are used to reduce and enlarge the "view" panel's view (and so the parabola).
I was recommended to use a scale var.
This is my code:

note: x0, y0 are panel_main x center, y center.
I have x, y that are used to determine x,y from the equation.
xpc, ypc are converted for the window scale (so are pixels).
xmin, xmax are the extreme values that, with a certain scale, stay on the panel

I hope you can give me a hint, thanks a lot!

```
public void DisegnaParabola()
{
     Graphics gs = panel_main.CreateGraphics();
     pen.Color = Color.Black;     

    scale = (x0*2) / zoom;        //Pixels equivalent to 1x or 1y
    n_punti = (x0*2) / scale;     //Number of x math points that are visible in window
    xmin = -(n_punti / 2);                    
    xmax = n_punti / 2;                          
    precision = 1 / scale;          //Increment of x to have 1px 
    if (asse_parabola.SelectedIndex == 0)   //if Y axis
    {
        for (double i = xmin + precision; i < xmax; i += precision)
        {
            rifx = i - precision;                      //Old points 
            rifxpc = rifx * scale;
            rify = (a * Math.Pow(rifx, 2)) + b * rifx + c;
            rifypc = y0 - (rify * scale);              

            x = i;                                     //New points
            y = (a * Math.Pow(x, 2)) + b * x + c;
            ypc = y0 - (y * scale);

            gs.DrawLine(pen, (float)rifxpc, (float)rifypc, (float)xpc, (float)ypc);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        scale = (y0*2) / zoom;        //Pixels for 1y
        n_punti = (y0*2) / scale;     //Numbers of y in the window
        ymin = -(n_punti / 2);                    
        ymax = n_punti / 2;

        for(double i=ymin+precision; i<ymax; i+=precision)
        {
            rify = y - precision;
            rifypc = (y0*2) - rify * scale;
            rifx = (a * Math.Pow(rify, 2)) + b * rify + c;
            rifxpc = x0 + (rifx * scale);

            y = i;
            x = (a * Math.Pow(y, 2)) + b * y + c;
            xpc = x0 + (x * scale);

            gs.DrawLine(pen, (float)rifypc, (float)rifxpc, (float)ypc, (float)xpc); 
        }

    }

    lbl_canc.Visible = true;


}
```

Comment: _Graphics gs = panel_main.CreateGraphics();_ This is the 1st mistake as the result will be non-persistent. EIther draw in the Paint event using its `e.Graphics` object (recommended here) or into a Bitmap. _gs.DrawLine_ using many `DrawLine`calls is also not recommended as they will look bad with any other pen than opaque with width=1. Collecting the Points and then using one `DrawLines`(plural!) call is better.. I don't see all the types but I hope you are aware of the integer division trap.. - Once you have a result you can show us, do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question actually consists of several tasks and as usual the key is to take and break those apart..

- One issue is getting the data, I will leave the details to you but show how to sparate it from the rest.
- The next issue is to scale the data. I'll show you how to avoid this one altogether and scale the drawing tool instead.
- And the third one is to draw them to a display surface. As you'll see this is really simple once the other issues are taken care of.

Let's start with the most important step: Collecting the data. You try to create and scale and draw them all in the same piece of code. This has many disadvantages..

Let's first collect the data in a suitable structure:

```
List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
```

`List<T>` is the collection of choice most of the time; certainly much nicer than arrays! In some method you should fill that list with your data, calculated from some formula.

Here is an example:

```
List<PointF> getPoints(float start, float end, int count, float ymax)
{
    List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
    float deltaX = (end - start) / count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        float x = i * deltaX;
        // insert your own formula(s) here!
        float y = ymax + (float)Math.Sin(x * somefactor) * ymax;
        points.Add(new PointF(x, y));
    }
    return points;
}
```

Now for the second important part: How to scale the data? This can be done either when creating them; but again, separating the two taks makes them both a lot simpler.

So here is a function that, instead of scaling the data scales the `Graphics` object we will use to plot them:

```
void ScaleGraphics(Graphics g, List<PointF> data)
{
    float xmax = data.Select(x => x.X).Max();
    float ymax = data.Select(x => x.Y).Max();
    float xmin = data.Select(x => x.X).Min();
    float ymin = data.Select(x => x.Y).Min();

    float width = Math.Abs(xmax - xmin);
    float height = Math.Abs(ymax - ymin);

    var vr = g.VisibleClipBounds;

    g.ScaleTransform(vr.Width / width, vr.Height / height);
}
```

This method makes sure that all the data in our list will fit into the drawing surface. If you want to restrict them to a different size you can pass it in and change the code accordingly..

Finally we need to do the actual drawing. We do that where we should, that is in the `Paint` event of our drawing surface control..:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (points.Count < 2) return;  // no lines to draw, yet
    ScaleGraphics(e.Graphics, points);
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    using ( Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue )
          { Width = 1.5f , LineJoin = LineJoin.Round, MiterLimit = 1f} )
        e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that, nice to have heard these new codes for me

Comment: Yes, (sorry for the delay) I finally managed to solve it. I did draw the parabole using DrawEllipse and the onPaint event to draw the axes at the application start.

Comment: If (and only if!) you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!

Comment: I was sure I've accepted it some time ago. If by "accepting" you mean clicking the up arrow near your post, I've done it. Of course it has been useful

Comment: __No, not the arrows__; they are for up- or downvoting. You need a little more rep to  do that. __Below__ the arrows is an (invisible) __checkmark__ which you can turn on/green by clicking it..